# gazebo linux mint 13 cinnamon

Tags: ros, linuxmint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a chance to run gazebo in Linux mint 13 cinnamon edition ?
I actually tried to install the pre-compiled package and tried to compile it myself but it is the same result

```
> hegazy@Loading ~ $ gazebo 
> Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.4.0
> Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source
> Robotics Foundation. Released under
> the Apache 2 License.
> http*//gazebosim*org
> 
> Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version
> 1.4.0 Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation. Released under
> the Apache 2 License.
> http*//gazebosim*org
> 
> Msg Waiting for master.Msg Waiting for
> master Msg Connected to gazebo master
> @ http*//127.0.0.1:11345 Msg
> Publicized address: 192.168.1.2
> 
> Msg Connected to gazebo master @
> 127.0.0.1:11345 Msg Publicized
> address: 192.168.1.2 hegazy@Loading ~
> $ gazebo my.world  Gazebo multi-robot
> simulator, version 1.4.0 Copyright (C)
> 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
> Released under the Apache 2 License.
> http*//gazebosim*org
```

my gazebo gui show and exit immedietly without any error or warning!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57534/gazebo-linux-mint-13-cinnamon/) by [Ahmed Hegazy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4383/ahmed-hegazy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this should be asked at http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0